# Python and Bash: how to automate user input?

Tags: python, bash

I downloaded some scripts in both python and bash that prompt the user for command line input.  Since I run these scripts often, I would like to automatically supply the input to the programs.  I prefer not to modify the scripts.  Is there a way to do it without modifying the original code?

**[UPDATE]** thanks to EnabrenTane's advice, it seems to work pretty well, until I got to a line that read `password = getpass.getpass('password: ')`.  It complains the following:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.4/getpass.py", line 29, in unix_getpass
old = termios.tcgetattr(fd)     # a copy to save
termios.error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')
```

Any way to get around that?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/expect/

Comment: Why would you have expected the input to be printed twice?

Comment: kindall: because of the first advice @ http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/send-automatic-input-to-a-script-called-by-another-script-in-bash-programming-164502/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the password requirement, I ended up using **pexpect**, a python module that automates user input.

Answer (score 3):

Like this on bash: `$ ./python_script < input.txt`

**edit:**
Alternatively you could write your scripts to take `ARGV` as a file name to read from. You could reopen `STDIN` to the file and not have to change any other lines.

Answer (score 1):

Since the responses in via stdin:

cat answers | yourscript.py